# Localizing a modern xib-based Mac application

Tags: cocoa, macos, localization, xib

Ours is an open-source Mac application localized by volunteers. These volunteers will do their work on special localization builds of the software (with unstripped nibs), then send us the changes to integrate into the original xib and strings files.

The problem is that, while there is [a way to integrate string changes without blowing away previous size changes](http://www.bdunagan.com/2009/04/15/ibtool-localization-made-easier/), I can't see a way to integrate new string *and size* changes (as when we add or replace views).

The only way to do both that I can see is for localizers to work directly with the original xibs and send us diffs. That means they have to download the entire source code, not just a localizable version of the release, work in Xcode as well as IB, and either run the diff command themselves (per xib) or install and use Mercurial.

Is there any better way for a xib-based application?

Answer (score 33):

**UPDATE** January 2014: Apple’s ‘autolayout’ code combined with their ‘Base’ localization stuff took most my ideas and improved on them. I recommend against using my old tools that I talk about in this answer. But, also, man was I right!

---

I strongly strongly STRONGLY recommend against frame changes in localizations. I know this runs counter to Apple's advice, but there are SO MANY problems with allowing frame changes - you end up with a billion edge cases.

Imagine you have 10 XIBs in your app, and you support 12 languages. You've got 120 different layouts to support, now. You just can't do this.

Change the strings, leave the views where they are. Make 'em bigger in ALL languages, if you need to. It sounds like this shouldn't work but it does. (I won three Apple Design Awards with an app that's localized in 10 or so languages this way.)

Specifics:

- For radio and checkboxes, just let them extend far to the right, beyond the last English character. That also provides a nice big landing area for imprecise mousers.
- For buttons, they should be wide anyhow, because it never looks good to have text cramped in the middle of the buttons.
- For titles on tableview columns, you should autosize when you load 'em up, if needed.
- For explanatory text, you should have some extra space to the right, and maybe an extra line. It just makes the English version of the XIB seem less cluttered. Sure, the Germans are going to see a slightly tighter XIB, but, hey, they're Germans -- they're probably used to that. There's probably even a German word for it. "Deutscheninterfakkenclutterlongen."
- If a text field is centered, just add equal space on both sides. There's no reason not to.

I've combined this with scripts that suck all the strings out of my XIBs and put them in .strings files, and then dynamically put the strings back at run-time, so anyone can localize my app without any special tools. Just drop in a bunch of .strings files and run it!

Blog post including full source: [Lost in Translations]¹.

Comment: What about right-to-left languages, such as Hebrew and Arabic?

Comment: That's a good point... I kind of wonder what they do for checkboxes anyhow.

One thing you could do is resize text boxes to be *smaller* if needed when the NIB loads and the localization doesn't require the whole space -- I started work on this but never finished it.

Comment: [I'll probably worry about it if I ever get any Hebrew or Arabic localizations -- sadly the hot Israeli girl I was dating dumped me.]

Comment: Maybe you should have had a Hebrew localization then!

Comment: And the complete blog post for reference:
http://wilshipley.com/blog/2009/10/pimp-my-code-part-17-lost-in.html

Comment: Good advice, it is good practice to accommodate for text expansion right from the start in your source language. +1 also for "Deutscheninterfakkenclutterlongen"! :)

Answer (score 3):

I confess that I'm not all that familiar with the process of localizing Mac apps. But I did run across a script that's part of the [Three20 iPhone library](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20) that seems like it might be useful: [diffstrings.py](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/blob/master/diffstrings.py) is a Python script that "compares your primary locale with all your other locales to help you determine which new strings need to be translated. It outputs XML files which can be translated, and then merged back into your strings files."

**EDIT:** As a companion to [Wil Shipley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494999/localizing-a-modern-xib-based-mac-application/1508612#1508612) to this question, I'll add a link to [a blog post he just wrote](http://wilshipley.com/blog/2009/10/pimp-my-code-part-17-lost-in.html) that goes into more detail about localization, and provides some of the tools that he's built to ease the process.

Comment: That sounds a lot like my own Localization Helper, right down to only working with strings files, not xibs/nibs.

Answer (score 3):

Where I used to work, we had this issue as well.  Our app was getting translated into 10 different languages.

At first, we tried doing what Wil suggested, which is to make everything super wide and fit in every language.  Unfortunately, "online backup" might be pretty short in English, but in other languages (especially Spanish), it's really long ("copia de seguridad" just means "backup").  Widening our UI made everything look pretty terrible.

One day, I was playing around with some Core Animation stuff and discovered the [`CAConstraint`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CAConstraint_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) class.  `CAConstraint` is basically a way to define a layout relationship between two `CALayers`.  You give one layer a name (like "layerA") and then say "layerB is constrained [in such-and-such a way] to a sibling layer called layerA".  Then, whenever the layer named `layerA` is repositioned or resized, `layerB` automatically moves as well.  It's really neat, and it's just what we were looking for.

After a couple of days of work, I came up with what is now [`CHLayoutManager`](https://github.com/davedelong/CHLayoutManager).  It's basically a re-make of `CAConstraint` and friends, but for `NSViews`.  Here's a simple example of how it works:

```
CHLayoutConstraint * centerHorizontal = [CHLayoutConstraint constraintWithAttribute:CHLayoutConstraintAttributeMidX relativeTo:@"superview" attribute:CHLayoutConstraintAttributeMidX];
CHLayoutConstraint * centerVertical = [CHLayoutConstraint constraintWithAttribute:CHLayoutConstraintAttributeMidY relativeTo:@"superview" attribute:CHLayoutConstraintAttributeMidY];
[aView addConstraint:centerHorizontal];
[aView addConstraint:centerVertical];
```

This will keep `aView` centered in its superview, regardless of how the superview is resized.  Here's another:

```
[button1 setLayoutName:@"button1"];
[button2 addConstraint:[CHLayoutConstraint constraintWithAttribute:CHLayoutConstraintAttributeMinX relativeTo:@"button1" attribute:CHLayoutConstraintAttributeMaxX]];
[button2 addConstraint:[CHLayoutConstraint constraintWithAttribute:CHLayoutConstraintAttributeMaxY relativeTo:@"button1" attribute:CHLayoutConstraintAttributeMaxY]];
[button2 addConstraint:[CHLayoutConstraint constraintWithAttribute:CHLayoutConstraintAttributeWidth relativeTo:@"button1" attribute:CHLayoutConstraintAttributeWidth]];
```

This will keep `button2` anchored to the right edge of `button1`, as well as keeping `button2`'s Y position and width the same as `button1`'s.

Internally, `CHLayoutManager` uses an `NSValueTransformer` to calculate the new positioning information.  Some of the `CHLayoutConstraint` initializers accept an `NSValueTransformer`, so you can create arbitrarily complex layout manipulations.

We used this for constraining and laying out the entire UI, and then doing all of the localization in code (and subsequently calling `-sizeToFit`, with some modifications).  Our UI would just flow into its final layout.  It turned out to be *extremely* convenient.  We'd just package up our `.strings` files, send them off to the translators, and then drop them in to place when we got them back, and our app would instantly be localized for that language.

`CHLayoutManager` isn't perfect.  It doesn't resolve conflicts, but simply applies constraints in the order they're added.  So you can constrain (for example) the `MinX` of a view 42 different ways, but only the last one will be used.  Also, if you constrain the MinX and the MaxX, they'll also be applied in the order they're added and will not end up stretching or shrinking the width.  In other words, constraining one attribute of a view will not affect the other attributes.  It's compatible with 10.5+ (GC and non).  However, due to some changes in Lion, it's unlikely that I'll address the shortcomings.

Despite these shortcomings, it's an extremely flexible framework, and (IMO) some pretty nifty code. (Plus, I swizzle `-[NSView dealloc]`! Yay!)

---

### Update

Now that AppKit has this same functionality (via [`NSLayoutConstraint`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLayoutConstraint/constraintWithItem%3aattribute%3arelatedBy%3atoItem%3aattribute%3amultiplier%3aconstant%3a)), I recommend using that system instead of `CHLayoutManager`.  It is far more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that XIB files are merely XML files in an obscure format, so you can translate those easily enough, provided that you can find what strings there are there to translate in the first place. For example, here's the snippet that creates a button called Jenson:

```
<object class="NSButtonCell" key="NSCell" id="41219959">
<int key="NSCellFlags">67239424</int>
<int key="NSCellFlags2">134217728</int>
<string key="NSContents">Jenson</string>
...
</object>
```

So you can get that string translated and then substitute occurrences of it in the XIB with your translated value. In order to verify it's working as expected, you could change the language to use random keys instead (like BUTTON_TITLE) which will make it easier to spot when one's missing.

However, the positions/sizes of the items are fixed, so you can have titles that overflow the space given in a different language. That's one of the reasons why Macs have separate XIB files for every language, to allow adjustments to be made on a language-by-language basis, however difficult it is to maintain.

Comment: I know all of that. That's the context of the question: How to get not just string changes but also frame changes from the translated nibs that the localizers send us into our localized xibs.