# iPhone addition to already localized nibs

Tags: iphone, localization, xib

I've submitted an app to the store that has been localised into a number of languages. Now it's time to update a few things, so I've added a few new components to a xib or two and modify them as IBOutlets from my code. All works great in English, but when I change to a different language it appears that my nib additions haven't been propagated through the localised nibs that already existed. (I get an unrecognised selector on a UILabel I've added).

What is the correct workflow for adding new items to an already localised nib? Should a modification to the top level .xib carry through to all localised versions? Or should I unlocalize, add new components and then localise all over again?

Many thanks,

Bryn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is nothing in Xcode that will automatically keep your localised nibs synchronised. You may want to check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494999/localizing-a-modern-xib-based-mac-application) and the [blog post](http://wilshipley.com/blog/2009/10/pimp-my-code-part-17-lost-in.html) by Wil Shipley on possible approaches you could take.